# Appending data to a .csv file from an HTML form

Tags: jquery, export-to-csv, forms

I created and maintaining a .csv file (File.csv). Whenever new devices arrives at my company, I wish add new line to this file, along with properties of the new device. I would like to update the .csv file using an HTML form. The .csv file is on our server. I don't want use a database. Is it possible to maintain such .csv file using jQuery? I read about that is possible only when creating a new csv file. I'm trapped with this and can't find a solution. I'm hoping somebody help me.

I have something like that:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="Device">
  <input type="text" name="Invoice">
  <input type="text" name="RAM">   
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile">
</form>
```

When I click on the button, I expect file.csv to be appended with new device on next line.

Comment: You have to send the data to server and manipulate the file there using whatever server side programming language is available

Comment: you really would normally use a database for this kind of thing. What's your objection?

Comment: because my boss does not want to use the database on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me:

I used appending data to a .csv via php. Maybe, it can to help someone.

```
<?php
$fileName='..\csv\devices.csv';

$fw = fopen($fileName, 'a');

$cells = array($_POST['date'], $_POST['invoice_number'], $_POST['evc_nr'], $_POST['device'], $_POST['sn'], $_POST['user'], $_POST['room']);

$row = join(",", $cells);

fwrite($fw, $row."\n");

fclose($fw);

header('Location: ..\index.html');

?>
```